# how to make the Invisible reCAPTCHA call in firebase to behave like a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

```
let isRecaptchaRendered = false;
const renderRecaptcha = async () => {
  recaptchaVerifier.current = await new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    "recaptcha-container", {
      size: "invisible",
      callback: () => {
        isRecaptchaRendered = true
      },
      "expired-callback": function() {
        console.log("reCaptcha expired")
      },
    }
  );
};

function onSubmit() {
  console.log("before rendering");
  await renderRecaptcha();
  console.log("after rendering");
  if (isRecaptchaRendered) {
    // get the further task done
  }
}
```

I wanted to halt the execution of the file until the reCAPTCHA callBack is called and the `isRecaptchaRendered` flag is set to true

Comment: How about creating a `function furtherTasks() {...}` and calling it from the `callback` of `recaptchaVerifer`? That way the code will run only after callback is triggered.

Comment: well i did try out to do so but some how the futureTasks() does not go ahead and execute . (i am using this in an react application)